# C++: Accessing parent methods and variables

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child, base-class

In which way should I access this parent method and parent variable?

```
class Base
{
public:
    std::string mWords;
    Base() { mWords = "blahblahblah" }
};

class Foundation
{
public:
    Write( std::string text )
    {
        std::cout << text;
    }
};

class Child : public Base, public Foundation
{
    DoSomething()
    {
        this->Write( this->mWords );
        // or
        Foundation::Write( Base::mWords );
    }
};
```

Thanks.

Edit: And what if there is ambiguity?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two syntaxes you use in your code (`this->...` and qualified names) are only necessary specifically when there is ambiguity or some other name lookup issue, like name hiding, template base class etc.

When there's no ambiguity or other problems you don't need any of these syntaxes. All you need is a simple unqualified name, like `Write` in your example. Just `Write`, not `this->Write` and not `Foundation::Write`. The same applies to `mWords`.

I.e. in your specific example a plain `Write( mWords )` will work just fine.

---

To illustrate the above, if your `DoSomething` method had `mWords` parameter, as in

```
DoSomething(int mWords) {
  ...
```

then this local `mWords` parameter would hide inherited class member `mWords` and you'd have to use either

```
DoSomething(int mWords) {
  Write(this->mWords);
}
```

or

```
DoSomething(int mWords) {
  Write(Foundation::mWords);
}
```

to express your intent properly, i.e. to break through the hiding.

---

If your `Child` class also had its own `mWords` member, as in

```
class Child : public Base, public Foundation
{
  int mWords
  ...
```

then this name would hide the inherited `mWords`. The `this->mWords` approach in this case would not help you to unhide the proper name, and you'd have to use the qualified name to solve the problem

```
DoSomething(int mWords) {
  Write(Foundation::mWords);
}
```

---

If both of your base classes had an `mWords` member, as in

```
class Base {
public:
  std::string mWords;
  ...
};

class Foundation {
public:
  int mWords;
  ...
```

then in `Child::DoSomething` the `mWords` name would be ambiguous, and you'd have to do

```
DoSomething(int mWords) {
  Write(Foundation::mWords);
}
```

to resolve the ambiguity.

---

But, again, in your specific example, where there's no ambiguity and no name hiding all this is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most common approach:

```
Write(mWords);
```

unless you run into ambiguity.

If there's ambiguity or shadowing because you want something in a (particular) base class but something in another base class (or this class) hides it, then use the `Base::name` syntax.

If a local variable is shadowing one of your members, then use `this->`, though in general you should try to avoid this situation. (ie: try to avoid naming locals such that they shadow members)

I suppose one way to look at it would be to use the first of these that works and does what you want:

1. `name`
2. `this->name`
3. `Base::name`

Comment: yes, I might have to deal with ambiguity... I will clarify in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no naming conflict, simply use `Write(mWords)`. Use the other 2 if you have local variables that conflict, or when the names are hidden.

Comment: If there is conflict, which method do you recommend I use?

Comment: and what do you mean by "when the names are hidden"?

Comment: if it's a conflict between local variables and member variables (e.g. your class has a member variable `i`, and your method also uses a local variable `i`), use `this`. if `A` declares a function `f`, and `B` inherits `A` and declares `f` also, and you want to call `A`'s `f` from `B`, then use `A::f`.