# I have created the extended shortwavemessage in veins how to access it in tracidemo?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have created the extended wave message as:
    cplusplus {{
    #include "WaveShortMessage_m.h"

```
}}

//class noncobject Coord;

class WaveShortMessage; // // declare the message for later use.

message test extends WaveShortMessage{
        int wsmlength;  
        string wsmtData= "Test message and Testing it and Attack message";
}
```

How to access this type of extended message in TraciDemo11p.cc? Is it same as that of the waveshortmessage.msg or it will be different. I tried but I can not access.

Comment: Were you able to follow one of OMNeT++'s tutorials on creating own and derived message types? This looks very similar.

Comment: I could not find OMNeT++'s tutorials on creating own and derived message types. Are you talking about TIctoc tutorial?

Comment: @ Christoph: Where can I find  OMNeT++'s tutorials on creating own and derived message types?

Comment: The [OMNeT++ user manual's section on message inheritance](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec:ch-msg-defs:inheritance) explains the concept succinctly: a message definition like `packet Ieee80211DataFrame extends Ieee80211Frame` is, quite simply, turned into C++ code like `class Ieee80211DataFrame : public Ieee80211Frame`. This means you can use all features of C++ inheritance in your code. For more details on how to access inherited members in C++, please refer to the StackOverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4523545/4707703

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks like Java to me.

Not quite sure if I understand your question, but if you want your derived class to inherit from `WaveShortMessge` and access the test message, you can try the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class WaveShortMessage {}; 

class MessageTest : public WaveShortMessage {

  private:
    int wsmlength;  
    std::string wsmtData;

  public:
    MessageTest() : wsmtData("Test message and Testing it and Attack message") {}
    std::string getWsmtData() {
      return wsmtData; 
    }   

};

int main() {
  MessageTest mt; 
  std::cout << mt.getWsmtData() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Itsbriany; I am using Omnet++ with Veins for VANET. I want to modify this .cc file :[link](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc) https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc.  In omnet, while compling  the *.msg will generate .h and .cc files with getter and setter. I want to know the correct format to access the test parameter or fields. Thank you.