# Class template with enum specific implementation and shared functionality (CRTP)

Tags: c++

I want to design a `Matrix` class which allows to specify the method of memory management, i.e.

```
Matrix<Allocator::vector, int> mv(2, 2);
Matrix<Allocator::unique_pointer, int> mu(2, 2);

mv(1, 1) = 1;
mu(1, 2) = 1;
```

and with `mv` and `mu` being compatible to each other (i.e. when I overload the "+" operator) despite different memory strategies.

I found already very good help from [Class template specializations with shared functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757816/class-template-specializations-with-shared-functionality) which does the same for an n dimensional vector class.

```
using dim_t = std::pair<size_t, size_t>;

enum class Allocator { vector, raw_pointer, unique_pointer };

template <typename T>
class MatrixBase {
 public:
  MatrixBase() : MatrixBase(0, 0){};
  MatrixBase(size_t m, size_t n) : dim_(m, n){};

  size_t rows() const;

  virtual T& at(size_t i, size_t j);

 private:
  dim_t dim_;
};

template <typename T>
size_t MatrixBase<T>::rows() const {
  return dim().first;
}

template <Allocator A, typename T>
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<T> {};

template <typename T>
class Matrix<Allocator::vector, T> : public MatrixBase<T> {
 private:
  std::vector<T> data_;
};

template <typename T>
T& Matrix<Allocator::vector, T>::at(size_t i, size_t j) {
  return data_[i * rows() + j];
}

template <typename T>
class Matrix<Allocator::unique_pointer, T> : public MatrixBase<T> {
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<T[]> data_;
};

template <typename T>
T& Matrix<Allocator::unique_pointer, T>::at(size_t i, size_t j) {
  return data_[i * rows() + j];
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler complains

```
./matrix.hpp:100:34: error: out-of-line definition of 'at' does not match any declaration in 'Matrix<linalg::Allocator::vector,
      type-parameter-0-0>'
T& Matrix<Allocator::vector, T>::at(size_t i, size_t j) {
  ^
./matrix.hpp:103:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rows'
  return data_[i * rows() + j];
```

I assume the error originates from

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix<Allocator::vector, T> : public MatrixBase<T> {
 private:
  std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: This is an illegal return type: `T& Matrix<Allocator::unique_pointer, T>`

Comment: @Viatorus fixed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed Your code. Here You go:

```
using dim_t = std::pair<size_t, size_t>;

enum class Allocator { vector, raw_pointer, unique_pointer };

template <typename T>
class MatrixBase {
 public:
  MatrixBase() : MatrixBase(0, 0){};
  MatrixBase(size_t m, size_t n) : dim_(m, n){};

  size_t rows() const;

  virtual T& at(size_t i, size_t j);

 private:
  dim_t dim_;
};

template <typename T>
size_t MatrixBase<T>::rows() const {
  return dim_.first;
}

template <Allocator A, typename T>
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<T> {};

template <typename T>
class Matrix<Allocator::vector, T> : public MatrixBase<T> {
    public:
        T &at(size_t i, size_t j);
    private:
        std::vector<T> data_;
};

template <typename T>
T& Matrix<Allocator::vector, T>::at(size_t i, size_t j) {
  return data_[i * this->rows() + j];
}

template <typename T>
class Matrix<Allocator::unique_pointer, T> : public MatrixBase<T> {
    public:
        T &at(size_t i, size_t j);
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<T[]> data_;
};

template <typename T>
T& Matrix<Allocator::unique_pointer, T>::at(size_t i, size_t j) {
  return data_[i * this->rows() + j];
}
```

First of all, if You override a method You have to declare it in derived class. Secondly, the `rows()` function could not be resolved by default as a member.

Comment: Why is `this->` required? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523545/c-accessing-parent-methods-and-variables says that it is only necessary if ambiguity exists but I don't see any naming conflict

Comment: @bodokaiser Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer

Comment: You don't have to declare an override method in your derived class. That is wrong. My answer showed that.

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition inside will solve the problem. This problem is due to scoping.

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix<Allocator::vector, T> : public MatrixBase<T> {
public: // or private:
    T& at(size_t i, size_t j) {
        return data_[i * MatrixBase<T>::rows() + j];
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

Consider the following example

```
class P {
    public:
        virtual int test();
};

class C : public P {
};

int C::P:: test() { // if you omit P, it will not compile
    return 21;
}
```

Or you can re-declare it inside `C`, so it will be in `C`'s scope.